# Current page name overlapping with other chapters

Tags: margins, chapters, book-design

I am writing my thesis on latex, and every pages show at the bottom the name of the current chapter. The code is the following:

```
\documentclass[openany, a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[top=4cm, bottom=4cm, left=3.5cm, right=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{nameref}


\makeindex

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{-2\p@}}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\section}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{-4\p@}}}{}{}

\newif\if@chapters
\@ifundefined{chapter}{\@chaptersfalse}{\@chapterstrue}
\if@chapters
  \apptocmd{\@chapter}{\gdef\currentname{#1}}{}{}
%  \apptocmd{\@schapter}{\gdef\currentname{#1}}{}{}
\fi
%\apptocmd{\@sect}{\gdef\currentname{#7}}{}{}
\def\currentname{---Still no title given---}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Fully Homomorphic Encryption over an Artificial Neural Network}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\currentname}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}


\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1~}

\hypersetup{
    backref=true,
    pagebackref=true,
    allcolors=black
}

\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}




\begin{document}

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\printindex
Text...
\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}  

\tableofcontents


\mainmatter
\chapter{test1}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\printindex
\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}  
\phantomsection
\chapter{test2}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\printindex
\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}  
\phantomsection
\chapter{test3}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\printindex
\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}  
\phantomsection
\chapter{test4}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\printindex
\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}  
\phantomsection

\chapter*{Conclusion}
Conclusion

\printindex
\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}  
\phantomsection

\backmatter

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

On my main file, I have a chapter for the Acknowledgments, then the Contents, and then I insert the different part of my thesis `\include{ChapterX}`
then I include the bibliography.

However, with this code, I have ''Acknowledgements'' written in the bottom of the pages of the Contents and the name of the last chapter on the pages for the bibliography.

All my chapters are listed except actually Acknowledgements, does the problem come from there? If other parts of the code are required, please let me know.

[image: Example of error in the table of contents]

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) please provide a full (but minimal) example instead of a sniplet like this. An MWE makes it a lot easier for others to help as they can just copy your code and test is as is. Here we have to guess a lot, and thus a lot of people pass your question as there are others that are easier to approach

Comment: I just edited the first message, I hope this is enough (the missing parts are only the modifications of layouts for theorems, definition, etc... so i don't think it's relevant here)

Comment: You are including files (chapters) that we do not have access to, perhaps replce those `include` lines with some relevant sample data

Comment: I mean the chapters have nothing specific, just a bunch of sections loaded with texts...

Comment: I edited the first message to show the layout of chapters

Comment: Put that into the original MWE, there is rarely any need to work with separate files

Comment: plus you are missing a `\makeatletter`

Comment: For me your MWE does not show the effect you are describing.

Comment: Well I have more than 80 pages right now, so it is more convenient to separate I think..
I deleted ```\makeatletter``` when editing I guess, I added it back!
But without considering the chapters, I have the same problem with the content pages, where "Acknoledgements" is written on the bottom of the pages.. And acknowledgements is a ```\chapter*``` in the main file

Comment: Now the MWE contains absolutely everything, except the contents of the chapters.. And I still have this issue for the Table of Contents and the Bibliography, I don't understand...

Comment: I forgot to mention, even if I believe you can see it with my options, that the ```\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\currentname}``` does not appear on the first pages of the chapters / tableofcontents / etc... The problem appears on the next pages of the ```\tableofcontents```

Comment: I still do not see any issues with the mwe you provide, please make sure to test before you post. Perhaps take a screen shot of the issue and add it to your question. As it sits not, I cannot help as I do not see any issues.

Comment: BTW: you should not be adding LOF, LOT etc to the TOC like that, if LOF is several pages then the toc entry is on the wrong page. Use the `tocbibind` package, then they are automatically included in the TOC (or switch to the memoir class where such things are already build into the class)

Comment: I will correct the LOF, LOT issue.. As the MWE contains absolutely everything I have, I will upload a screenshot of the issue. If it really does not help you, I'll add my content to try to show the error...

Comment: You need the MWE to show the error at your end, if we cannot recreate it on our end something is wrong at your end.

Comment: I edited it with an example, same code, to show my problem. If you run this toy example, you will have - Still no title given - written in the bottom page of the contents. In my complete file, this text is Acknowledgements, which I don't want because it is a former chapter and shouldn't be printed at the bottom of the toc

Answer (score 1):

```
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\currentname}
```

defines on every page the chapter name in the footer. For the first page
of a numbered or unnumbered chapter the page style is by default `plain` and not `fancy`. If you 
want to redefine it in the same way then use

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
  \fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\currentname}%
  \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}%
}
```

Comment: With your correction, it actually inverses my problem... Now "Acknowledgements" is visible on the footer of the first page of the TOC only, instead of all the other pages of the TOC

Comment: I found something which is part of a solution, while not so elegant. I wrote
```\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{fancy}{ 
  \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
  \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}}}} ```

However now, while I don't have this problem, I have only roman notations for the page numbers inside the TOC, and all page numbers in the following footers are stuck at '1'